# Using svn through ssh connection on mac

Tags: svn, macos, ssh, terminal

I have a project that I could sync with the svn server only at the company I work for.

now I work remotly on the project from a different country and so I can't go to the company to commit the project.

Therefore we set up a ssh account to be able to commit with the server of the company.

the problem is I have no idea how to use the ssh connection to sync with the serveur.

here is what I got

1) I have an existing project with all my modifications and setup up to commit the project locally.

2) I have a working ssh connection to the server

what command do I need to type to commit my changes ?

(I use a **mac** and the terminal to commit/update)

Comment: You might want to edit the title of this question to be, "How can I switch the protocol of an SVN checkout?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an existing checkout of the repository with changes you want to commit, the easiest thing to do is use `svn switch` to change the URL that the checkout uses for the repository:

```
svn switch --relocate http://repository.url/path svn+ssh://repository.url/path
```

For details, see [the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy: you can use "svn+ssh" urls. For example, to check out the project

```
svn co svn+ssh://servername.company.com/path/to/repository localname
```

Then copy your changes into the checked-out copy, and commit normally

```
svn commit -m "Log msg"
```

Comment: No luck when I do svn co svn+ssh://X.X.X.X:P .
 I get a Network connection closed unexpectedly. lets I have address X.X.X.X of the server, to use port P and a login l on the ssh connection what should I be inputing as a command (sorry I'm useless with a terminal)

Comment: Then svn co svn+ssh://l@X.X.X.X/path/to/repository

Comment: The "switch" thing mentioned by @Drew Stephens is also an option, although it's easier to accidentally hose your working copy/lose your changes if you don't do it right, so I'd be careful.

Comment: It's also possible to put "virtual host entries" in your SVN config files; see, for example, http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-09/0574.shtml

Comment: Hi I'm guetting a Syntac error parsing revision 'X.X.X.X' (also I don't think I should be adding the SVN_SSH to the request otehrwise why did we export it)

Comment: `svn+ssh://` tells svn to contact a host via ssh, and run svn on that remote host to do its work. The SVN_SSH environment variable tells `svn` what `ssh` command line to use. You absolutely need both! If svn is thinking X.X.X.X is a revision number, then you're probably including spaces where there should be none. There are no spaces anywhere from svn+... to the end of the repository path -- it's all one long word.

Comment: Ok I got more information about the problem. the ssh connection is not the svn server so no luck with svn+ssh. so I have to use ssh -L P1:X.X.X.X:P2  and then use svn co svn://localhost:P1/path, but the problem is I keep getting a "no repository found"